# Regular or Extended license for Theme/Module bought by a client?

Tags: licensing

As a freelancer who provides mostly backend development/ setup of the software, sometimes I'm required to install 3rd party modules bought/ owned by a client.

As an example, if customer has bought envato theme with regular license, is it ok for me to use it even though I'm technically charging for the end product?

Also client owns the end product after development is done.

Thank you!

Comment: Licensing is specific to many factors. In what regards your example, I recall that Envato has multiple licensing options. You can do whatever you want as long as you stay in the boundaries of the licence. If the licence is per project or per developer make sure you are the only developer that uses it or that you are using it for only one project.

Answer (score 1):

If the client purchased the license, it is perfectly fine for you to include the product as part of your development *for this client*.

You should *not* use the product for *any* other clients in the future however.

---

Imagine you are a home builder. You get hired to build a home. Your client goes out and purchases all the (correct) lumber for the build, gives it to you and says, "Here, use this." -- You're fine building the home with client-supplied lumber. It actually saves you the time and trouble of sorting out what you need to purchase and determining what type of lumber the client would prefer. The only difference is you *can't* mark-up the lumber costs and pass them on to the client.